# apache2 RewriteRule target single question mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Could someone explain what a single **?** placed at the **Target** of an RewriteRule in apache2 means?

```
Syntax:
RewriteRule pattern target [Flag1,Flag2,Flag3]

RewriteRule ^       ?      [END,E=error-notes:blacklisted-user-agent]
or
RewriteRule .*      ?      [F,L]
```

And where's the `error-notes` environment variable used?

---

What i know so far:

- **END** Flag is [explained here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html).
- The **pattern** is an regular expression and means "match all", [see here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It effectively drops the query string, so for example `/posts?page=5` would become to `/posts?`.

Not sure about `error-notes`.